# A prime order group must be cyclic

Tags: group-theory

I have a question about prime order group. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340742/help-me-to-prove-that-group-is-cyclic) answer by amWhy says that:

> It follows that any group of order 5 (and any group of prime order) must be generated by a single element and is hence, cyclic.

I understand previous part but this. If any group of prime order must be generated by a single element??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a group and that $G$ has prime order.  Now pick some $g\in G$ with $g\not=e$.  Then consider the group $\{g^n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  This is a nonzero subgroup of $G$.  By LaGrange's theorem, its order must divide the order of $G$.  But since the order of $G$ is prime, it must be all of $G$.

Comment: Either you spell it *la Grange* or *Lagrange*. The latter is what he used. The spelling *LaGrange* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be a non-identity element of the group $G$.  The order of $g$ is a divisor of the order of the group, which is prime, say $p$. The order isn't one, so it must be $p$.

Now in general, $|\langle g \rangle|$ equals the order of $g$.  For us this means $|\langle g \rangle | = p$ which is the order of the group. So $\langle g \rangle$ is a subset of $G$ which has the same size as $G$.  We must have $\langle g \rangle =G$, thus $G$ is generated by the element $g$.